# NLogConfigurationException: Error loading extensions: NLog.Extended

Tags: .net-6.0, nlog

I am following this post to configure NLog to write to a text file in my .Net 6.0 Web api project

https://medium.com/projectwt/nlog-with-ilogger-in-net-6-0-web-api-fb7072d8ac6c

But when I run the project I get these errors

> NLogConfigurationException: Error loading extensions: NLog.Extended
>
> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'NLog.Extended,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file
> specified.

on this line

```
var app = builder.Build();
```

I tried to search for `NLog.Extended` nuget package but found out that it is deprecated and the suggested substitute package is `NLog.MSMQ` so I installed it but that too did not help.

So I added the deprecated package `NLog.Extended` and then the error went away.

Now everything is working fine but the package `NLog.Extended` is definitely not made for .NET 6 and so I see this warning

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nuget-package-package page for [NLog.Extended](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extended) says:

> NLog.Extended nuget-package will no longer be released, and should be removed

There nothing in the [guide that you posted](https://medium.com/projectwt/nlog-with-ilogger-in-net-6-0-web-api-fb7072d8ac6c) that mentions adding [NLog.Extended](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extended) as project-dependency. Also NLog.Extended only works with .NET Framework (and not with target-platforms like NET6/NET8)

I suggest that you remove [NLog.Extended](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extended)-nuget-package from your application (both as nuget-package-dependency and also from `NLog.config`-file). If you depend on the VERY exotic [MSMQ-target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MSMQ-target), then you can consider adding the dedicated [NLog.MSMQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.MSMQ/)-nuget-package.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out of removing the `NLog.Extended` dependency from `NLog.config` file. That was the thing causing it. I copied the `NLog.config` file from one of my projects and that project was using the extension `NLog.Extended` in config file. After your comment I checked the file and find its reference in the file and removed it, now it working fine :)